# Is there accepted name for digraph segement without "joins" or "turns"?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

As example lets consider following directed graph:

```
Z--                -->D
    \            / 
      ->A-->B-->C
    /            \
Y--                -->F
```

In `A->B->C` part there are no "joins"/"turns".

(opposite of that would be any path that includes `A` or `C` not as starting/ending vertex, as `A` has two incoming edges and `C` has two outgoing edges)

How one would unambiguously call that? (linear segment?)

Edit:
My attempt at clarification of the question.

Given graph $G$, is there accepted term for connected induced subgraph $H$,

which edges satisfy $\forall xy \in E(H) \Rightarrow (deg^+(x)_G\leq 1 \land deg^-(y)_G \leq 1) $?

(Subscript $G$ in $deg^+(x)_G$ marks that degree is counted in graph $G$ (as opposed to subgraph $H$))

Edit-2:
Couple of related terms/concepts:

- [Subdivision and smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_(graph_theory)#Subdivisions) (also "Homeomorphism" under same link)
- [Series-ReducedTree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Series-ReducedTree.html)

Comment: Are you simply looking for a path? That is, a directed graph is a "linear segment" (or whatever you wish to call it) if its undirected version is [a path.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you're asking:

> **Question.** What do we call--and how should we define--subgraphs with the following property?
>
> 1. (Thinness) Given nodes $x$ and $y$, there is at most one path from $x$ to $y$.
> 2. (Totality) Given nodes $x$ and $y$, either there is a path from $x$ to $y$, or there is a path from $y$ to $x$, or both.

Firstly, observe that the conditions for linearity are completely internal conditions--that is, they make no mention of the larger graph in which our subgraph is embedded. Hence, we can phrase the definition for digraphs *themselves*, rather than for subgraphs of digraphs.

With that out of the way, I would advise simply calling them *linear*:

> **Definition 0.** A digraph $D$ is *linear* iff the category of paths of $D$ is both *thin* and *total.*

To complete the definition, we need to explain the terms "thin" and "total."

> **Definition 1.** Let $\mathbf{C}$ denote a category. Then:
>
> - $\mathbf{C}$ is *thin* iff every pair of parallel arrows is equal.
> - $\mathbf{C}$ is *total* iff for all objects $X$ and $Y$, either there exists an arrow $X \rightarrow Y$, or there exists an arrow $Y \rightarrow X$, or both.

In summary, you can then say: "observe that the subgraph $\{A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C\}$ is linear" or "observe that the subgraph induced by $\{A,B,C\}$ is linear."

Lets now define:

> **Definition 2.** Let $D$ denote a digraph. A *turn* in $D$ is a node $x$ of $D$ with out-degree $\geq 1$. That is, it is a node $x$ of $D$
>    such that there exist *distinct* nodes $a,b$ of $D$ and arrows $x
>  \rightarrow a$ and $x \rightarrow b$. A *join* in $D$ is a node $y$ of
>    $d$ with in-degree $\geq 1$. That is, it is a node $x$ of $D$ such
>    that there exist *distinct* nodes $a,b$ of $D$ and arrows $a
>  \rightarrow x$ and $b \rightarrow x$.

You should then be able to prove:

> **Proposition.** A digraph is linear iff it is connected, and has no joins or turns.

Note that the following digraph has no joins or turns, but nonetheless isn't linear according to our definition, because it isn't connected:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}A_0 \rightarrow B_0 \rightarrow C_0\\A_1 \rightarrow B_1 \rightarrow C_1\end{matrix}\right\}$$

Comment: I think it's wonderful that you are able to decipher the question. To make your answer more useful to dummies like me, would you mind stating in plain language what the OP is asking? What is a "segment" of a digraph, is it just an (induced?) subgraph? What are "joins" and "turns" in this context? (Yes, I am really that ignorant.) And how is $\{A\to B\to C\}$ total? Are we supposed to imagine an arrow between $A$ and $C$? Does it matter which way it points?

Comment: @Bof I can try to decipher for you what I meant in original question.
Imagine my example graph as a map of one-way streets. (like city map on a paper)
There is "join" of streets at `A` (coming from `Z` and `Y`). There is possible 'turn' at `C` (either to `D` or `F`)
Between `A` and `C` one could drive only straight.
My question was if there is accepted name for such "straight only" section.

Comment: haha you're funny @bof. I just fixed/improved/rewrote my answer, so hopefully that helps.